# Got only a black image on TensorBoard

Tags: tensorboard

I tried image_summaries.ipynb , it ran well and displayed image correctly.

Then I wrote some code, but the image does not display, I only have a black image.

---

```
img = np.reshape(train_images[0], (-1, 28, 28, 1))
print(img.shape)
```

> (1, 28, 28, 1)

```
img[0][20]
```

> array([[  0],[  0],[  0],[  0],[  0],[  0],[ 
>   0],[ 15],[220],[253],[253],[ 80],[  0],[  0],
>          [  0],[  0],[  0],[  0],[  0],[  0],[  0],[  0],[  0],[  0],[  0],[  0],[  0],[  0]])

```
!rm -rf logs
logdir = "logs/train_data/" + datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
file_writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer(logdir)
with file_writer.as_default():
  tf.summary.image("Training data", img, step=0)
%tensorboard --logdir logs/train_data
```

---

Could someone explain it to me?

[image: BLACK image]

Answer (score 2):

In fact, I found a solution

```
img = img.astype(np.uint8)
```

Even if [253] looks like an integer, it is probably not an integer...

With :

```
.astype(np.uint8)
```

I can see the image